# polygon material in Open_GL

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

Im trying to change the material of a polygon but its not working, I dont know why,

The polygon isnt affected by the GL_AMBIENT, GL_DIFFUSE, GL_SPECULAR and GL_SHININESS.

```
GLfloat mat_ambient[] = { 1, 0.5, 0, 1.0 };
GLfloat mat_diffuse[] = { 0.4, 0.2, 0, 1.0 };
GLfloat mat_specular[] = { 0.774597, 0.774597, 0.774597, 1.0 };
GLfloat mat_shine = 0.6;

glMaterialfv (GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, mat_ambient);
glMaterialfv (GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, mat_diffuse);
glMaterialfv (GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, mat_specular);
glMaterialf (GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, mat_shine * 128);


glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(axeX, axeY, 0);
glRotatef(angle, 0, 0, 1);

glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

    glNormal3f(0,0,1);
    glVertex3f (-0.25, 0.5, 1.0);

    glVertex3f (-0.5, 0.25, 1.0);

    glVertex3f (-0.5, -0.25, 1.0);

    glVertex3f (-0.25, -0.5, 1.0);

    glVertex3f (0.25, -0.5, 1.0);

    glVertex3f (0.5, -0.25, 1.0);

    glVertex3f (0.5, 0.25, 1.0);

    glVertex3f (0.25, 0.5, 1.0);

glEnd();
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: Have you turned on and set up lighting?

Comment: Yes. I have spheres and cubes too and that its working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you `glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)` and as ananthanonline suggests, make sure lighting is set up.

EDIT:

sorry you'll maybe need, 
    `glDisable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)`

Since enabling it specifies per-vertex colouring.  Though thinking about it, it may not have any effect since you are not specifying vertex colours.

Could you show the way that the lights are set up?  What colours have you specified on the light for specular/diffuse etc?

Comment: Where should I enable GL_COLOR_MATERIAL ?~

Comment: Can you please edit that code? I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Color Material is used to associate the glColor with one particular material setting. But the OP is already setting all material parameters. Actually he should double check, that color material doesn't interfer with his parameters.

Comment: @datenwolf yes my bad.  I shouldn't be posting late in the evening.